# Moving toward algorithm Python

Tags: python, sfml

I've recently started working with PySFML, and that's my first experience with multimedia programming.

I'm trying to get an object moving from point A to point B, B being the location of the mouse when i click and A the objects location at the same moment. Nothing really hard, I agree.
Here's my code :

```
def moveToward(self, point):
    start = self.circle.position
    end = sf.Vector2(point.x, point.y)
    direction = sf.Vector2(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y)
    lengthDir = math.sqrt(math.pow(direction.x, 2) + math.pow(direction.y, 2))
    dirNorm = sf.Vector2(direction.x / lengthDir, direction.y / lengthDir)
    self.dir = dirNorm
```

But, this doesn't work. When i click, the object moves toward a point which is not exactly the opposite, but definetely not the point where i clicked.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Take a moment to learn some debugging, for example you might put some print statements somewhere in your code and see what the target point is then, if it's not what you would expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The problem was that the mouse position is relative to the screen not the window.